i have added firebase_analytics: ^10.9.0 library to my project , then i am not able to build in iOS(Xcode) and android side is working fine

i have installed firebase Analytics in flutter using VSCode, below issue i am facing while running in xcode,
i have updated all pods, ruby etc, nothing will worked for me.

i have resolved the issue using below steps,
Open Xcode -> select project -> build settings ->
Search for

"$(inherited)" In Other Linker Flags.

Build Active Architecture Only value to "Yes".

Clean your project

Build your project.


Happy Coding.
